# Using Github Actions REST API, how to correlate reruns to the original run similar to the UI?

Tags: github-actions, github-api, cicd

I'm trying to get all recent runs in my repo on a specific branch. I then want to be able to correlate them.

**Example**
Lets say I have 5 runs(01,02,03,04,05), 01-03 are fresh runs, 04 is rerun of 01 and 05 is rerun of 03.

How can I detect these rerun relations, similarly to how they're grouped in the UI dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can discover the desired relation between workflow runs using the [`/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs` API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-workflow-runs-for-a-repository). We will get workflow runs for the current repository. According to the response, the JSON contains `workflow_runs` array. Each workflow item contains `previous_attempt_url` property pointing to a previous run. If a particular run has no rerun attempt the property will be `null`. You can use the property to build a rerun tree.